# Installing faiss on Google Colaboratory

Tags: pip, conda, google-colaboratory, faiss

I try to follow instruction on the [MUSE project](https://github.com/facebookresearch/MUSE).

They require PyTorch and Faiss. PyTorch is easy to install. But I found problem with installing [Faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss).

The instruction on MUSE tell me to use

```
conda install faiss-cpu -c pytorch
```

But Google Colab doesn't support `conda` (When I tried `!pip install conda`, it didn't work)

And Faiss didn't work when I `!pip install faiss` either.

Is there a way to install Faiss or conda?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how I eventually install faiss.

```
!wget  https://anaconda.org/pytorch/faiss-cpu/1.2.1/download/linux-64/faiss-cpu-1.2.1-py36_cuda9.0.176_1.tar.bz2
!tar xvjf faiss-cpu-1.2.1-py36_cuda9.0.176_1.tar.bz2
!cp -r lib/python3.6/site-packages/* /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/
!pip install mkl
```

Then, I can `import faiss` with no problem. The warning is that I didn't use GPU. If you want to use GPU, you need to install this instead:

https://anaconda.org/pytorch/faiss-gpu/1.2.1/download/linux-64/faiss-gpu-1.2.1-py36_cuda9.0.176_1.tar.bz2

## Update June 2020

As @Kuffner said, you can now use `!pip` to install it. (I test and simplify it a bit)

For CPU

```
!apt install libomp-dev
!pip install faiss
```

For GPU

```
!pip install faiss-gpu
```

Answer (score 7):

As of June 2020 the easiest solution for Colab GPU runtime is:

```
!apt install libomp-dev
!python -m pip install --upgrade faiss faiss-gpu
import faiss
```

The code comes from [here: faiss/issues/890](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/issues/890)

Answer (score 5):

Try this solution, it should work!

```
!pip install faiss-cpu --no-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way!

1. install conda

   !wget -c -O anaconda.sh 'https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh'

   !bash anaconda.sh -b

   !cd /usr/bin/ && ln -sf /content/anaconda3/bin/conda conda

   !cd /content/
2. install faiss

   !yes y | conda install faiss-gpu -c pytorch

Comment: Here's the error after running the code. 

    ...
    Preparing transaction: - done
    Verifying transaction: | / - \ | / - \ | / - \ | / - \ | / - \ | / - \ done
    Executing transaction: / done
    yes: standard output: Broken pipe