# Installing Faiss on Lambda Stack

Tags: python, faiss

I want to install Faiss-GPU on Lambda Stack by `conda install -c pytorch faiss-gpu` but there is no conda installed.

I tried the solution mentioned here: [Installing faiss on Google Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967252/installing-faiss-on-google-colaboratory) with this version of faiss https://anaconda.org/pytorch/faiss-gpu/1.6.0/download/linux-64/faiss-gpu-1.6.0-py36h1a5d453_0.tar.bz2 but is says:

```
ImportError: libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_swigfaiss_avx2'

ImportError: libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_swigfaiss'
```

What is the correct way to install Faiss on Lambda Stack?

Comment: Have you tried pip? `pip install faiss-gpu`

Comment: Yes, it sais: `error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1`, I tried this https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/issues/314#issuecomment-309682572 but it didn't work.

Comment: Have tried compiling it from the source? https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/master/INSTALL.md#compile-from-source

Comment: Yes, when I try `make -C python`, it sais: `swigfaiss.cpp:173:11: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: I have got the same issue. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

if you are colab just try the following:

```
!sudo apt-get install libomp-dev
```

Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Lambda.

What worked for me was using a Linux version of the faiss-cpu library (I use macOS). I went to https://pypi.org/project/faiss-cpu/# and downloaded the .whl file in the version i was looking for (for me, it was `faiss_cpu-1.7.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl`).

Next go to the terminal and unzip it by doing

`unzip faiss_cpu-1.7.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl`.

This should give you the faiss-cpu version that will work on Lambda.

Then, zip everything up as you were doing before and upload it. In the end an incredibly frustrating problem was solved pretty simply.